# How can I trace RIA service messages

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-ria-services

Is there a way to see the messages that RIA services/clients send?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On server side, you could [enable WCF tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx). Is this what you're talking about or are you looking for a client-side solution?

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730342(VS.100).aspx